# Using OAuth2 for sending email with smtp and gmail

Tags: email, oauth-2.0, google-api, jwt, smtp

I want to send emails with java and smtp using OAuth2 access_token
I am able to do it if I use OAuth2 type that prompts the user with a browser to allow access.

Now I want to use a google service account and send a jwt json file to get the access token
As documented here
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

I get a response back from the token url (https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token)  that has a access_token, but it does not return a scope attribute and also has a ton of trailing periods

When I use it to call the smtp it responds with a 400 error

My Question is does gmail api work with jwt tokens?

Do I need to also have a Google Workspace Account or can I just use a normal Gmail Account?

EDIT FOLLOW UP:
I called the token validator url and got this back

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=xxx 

validateAccessToken response:  {
  "issued_to": "xxx",
  "audience": "xxx",
  "scope": "https://mail.google.com/",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "access_type": "online"
}
```

Not sure if it is the issue but access_type = "online" instead of offline like when I do it with 3 leg auth that requires user approval for access. Doing the JWT way I do not see anywhere to define access_type when requesting token

Comment: Do service accounts work with the smtp server?  I thought it just worked though the Gmail api.  Yes you need google workspace to use service accounts with the gmail api.  What language are you using?

Comment: My plan is once I use the jwt to get the access_token I should be able to pass it to smtp or imap like this (JAVA) <code> Properties props = System.getProperties(); props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp"); ... props.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2"); Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props); ... SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, null); transport.connect(smtpServerHost, smtpUserName, smtpUserAccessToken);</code>